# Determinants, Pfaffians, and...?

Tags: determinant

I recently stumbled across the [wikipedia entry on Pfaffians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) and found them rather interesting, especially the property below. (assuming $A$ is a $2n\times 2n$ skew symmetric matrix)
$$\det(A)=\mbox{pf}(A)^2$$
This got me thinking, does this go to higher powers? Is there such a determinant/Pfaffian type object with the following property?
$$\det(B)=\mbox{f}(B)^3$$